# (easy) How to remove the solid boundary of a shaded region

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-pic

I would like to remove the solid boundary of this shaded area. How should I do that?

Here is my code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=gray!30] plot[smooth, samples=100, domain=1:3.8] (-\x,\x) -| (0,0) -- cycle;
\path[fill] (0,0) circle (3.8pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

And the output:
[image]

Comment: Instead of `\draw[fill=gray!30] ...` just do`\fill[gray!30] ...`. Interestingly, you are using `\path[fill] ...` just below, `\path[fill=gray!30]...` would also work....

Comment: thanks, if you wish, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: problem solved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I answer this just to undo the downvote you received.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gray!30] plot[smooth, samples=100, domain=1:3.8] (-\x,\x) -| (0,0) -- cycle;
\path[fill] (0,0) circle (3.8pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Just for completeness: you don't need a smooth plot with 100 samples to draw a straight line. You'll get the same result with

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gray!30] (-1,1) -- (-3.8,3.8) -| (0,0) -- cycle;
\path[fill] (0,0) circle (3.8pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks +1, marmot, do you know precisely what "samples=100, domain=1:3.8" does? What does this ratio imply "domain=1:3.8"?

Comment: @wonderich `Samples` means it computes 100 points along the curves, and `1:3.8` is not a ratio, but `1` is the lower end of the domain and `3.8` its upper end. Of course, this is one of the most crazy ways I have seen so far to draw a straight line. ;-)

Comment: do you know how to change the overall scale of the figure? Is there something like [scale=...] for this, if we use the \begin{tikzpicture} and \begin{table} environment?

Comment: @wonderich Yes, precisely `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]` will scale it by a factor of 2.

Answer (score 1):

As @marmot suggests, replace `\draw[fill=gray!30]` with `\fill[gray!30]` or `\path[fill=gray!30]`.